# kivy android share image

Tags: android, python, kivy, pyjnius

I want to create share button that will use android ACTION_SEND intent for sharing image. It's my code:

```
from kivy.setupconfig import USE_SDL2


def share(path):
    if platform == 'android':
        from jnius import cast
        from jnius import autoclass
        if USE_SDL2:
            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
        else:
            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
        Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
        String = autoclass('java.lang.String')
        Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
        File = autoclass('java.io.File')

        shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        shareIntent.setType('"image/*"')
        imageFile = File(path)
        uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile)
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

        currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        currentActivity.startActivity(shareIntent)
```

But it doesn't work) It throws this error `jnius.jnius.JavaException: Invalid instance of u'android/net/Uri' passed for a u'java/lang/String'` in this line `shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)`. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found solution. You must cast uri to parcelable and then pass it to intent:

```
parcelable = cast('android.os.Parcelable', uri)
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, parcelable)
```

Answer (score 3):

This method will work in API 24 and latest :

```
def share(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
            from jnius import autoclass
            from jnius import cast
            import os
            
            StrictMode = autoclass('android.os.StrictMode')
            StrictMode.disableDeathOnFileUriExposure()
            
            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
            
            Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
            String = autoclass('java.lang.String')
            Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
            File = autoclass('java.io.File')

            shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            shareIntent.setType('"application/pdf"')

            path = os.path.join(primary_external_storage_path(),"test.pdf")

            imageFile = File(path)
            uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile)
            parcelable = cast('android.os.Parcelable', uri)
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, parcelable)

            currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
            currentActivity.startActivity(shareIntent)
```