# How do I implement a social share button in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

As the question stands, how do I go about implementing such a thing? How do I share items (Images, Texts, etc) from my Kivy app to social media such as Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, etc, especially from mobile (Android, iOS).

I did find [this](https://github.com/knappador/kivy-twitter) and [this](https://github.com/tito/p4a-facebook-example) example, which is a start, but they are fairy old and I could't get them to work.

If there is a module, that would be good. If not, what would be the steps to do it. I assume the process would be different for Android and iOS, is there a way to manage both, or would I need 2 versions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the platform in kivy for android or iOS and execute your subsequent function.In case of android ,you could  use pyjnius to enable the share button like in [kivy android share image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983649/kivy-android-share-image).